# What's the recommended way to do action caching in Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am now doing the upgrade from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.1. I found that `cache_action` is removed from the core and in the official guide, `actionpack-action_caching gem` is suggested for doing this. But in the README of the gem, I see `NOTE: It will continue to be officially maintained until Rails 4.1.`.

So what is the correct and recommended way to do action caching in Rails 4.1 or we could not do it in Rails 4.1 without other supporting gems now?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the [actionpack-action_caching](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-action_caching) and [actionpack-page_caching](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-page_caching) gems to regain functionality. But be forewarned, both gems state:

> It will continue to be officially maintained until Rails 4.1

Or, maybe it's time to dive in and learn Rails 4.0+ russian doll caching scheme. Rails guides has an [excellent primer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html).